# How to prevent manual ssh remote port forwarding?

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a local script that takes certain data from users like their user id and a unique code. This script then ssh logins my server and send the user's parameter to a script in my remote server. That script later matches these data with a remote database, and if valid will set up the port forwarding connection. However, I just realized that users can also type ssh -r and manually connect to my server and forward ports. How do I prevent it?

EDIT: My Setup is as follows:

- The client is android, in an app called termux, that provides a Linux
  terminal.
- The script asks for a code, their user id(in my website) and a remote port
- The user then enters the details.
- The script will start ssh -R domain:port:localhost:port user@domain
  -i key -t "sudo script.ssh code, id, port"
- The script in the remote server validates the 3 parameters with the 
  database.
- If valid tell "Authentication successful. Press ctrl + c to exit"
- If the validation fails, it displays the error, sleep 5 and exit
- However, I can just ssh -r domain:port:localhost:port user@domain -i
  key and this will forward the ports.

I don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide advice without more intimate knowledge but -

What you are trying to do is likely not particularly secure or robust, and I get the impression that it breaks multiple security best practices (I might be reading too much into your statement " his script then ssh logins my server and send the user's parameter to a script in my remote server.  "

You can limit who can log in to an SSH server by modifying /etc/ssh/sshd_config and adding an appropriate AllowUsers command - however you would need to reload ssh when you modify this line.

Depending on how you set up SSHD you could also modify your configuration by setting "ForwardAgent no" for some or all hosts, although I suspect that is unlikely to be of much benefit.

**Added in response to clarification**

I struggle to get my head around the -R part of ssh but I don't think there is a good way of doing what you are attempting using ssh and a script.

You can possibly implement a limit by getting your script to add iptables rules to have the ports blocked by default, and then unblock it through the script- however this poses 2 hard problems -

1. How would you know when they were done to close the port. You might be able to change  to exit to a read command or similar that closes when the read is complete, but it is unlikely to be robust.    You might be able to use some complex magic and regex and use fail2ban to monitor for ssh closing the session and run another iptables rule or close script - but even if this is possible its messy and horrible and does not help with probable issue 2 below:
2. You are running the command "sudo script.ssh" from an SSH shell.  This would appear ripe for abuse (without knowing the script) as i expect people can presumably ssh into your server and view the script and get access to the database and exploit it - and that assumes you have set up sudo correctly.

Comment: Can I get some more explanation? Also, is my query unclear?

Comment: I confess I do find it difficult to understand what exactly you are doing, particularly how users relate to systems and how you are setting up the tunnel.  I can't provide more detail without further knowledge of your setup, but even then I'm not sure I can.

Comment: I think I have made it even more clear.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention something. First, the shell is rbash. So any command typed will give error. Second, the file is owned by root and is located in /usr/local/bin/pfs.sh. Permission is 500. So no one can edit it. /etc/sudoers/ has a rule to allow user pfs to execute pfs.sh using sudo without a password. So, I am sure that no one can cat or nano the script as the commands "cat and nano" are not found and also they do not have permission to read it.